# Checking if array is growing and print the missing element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration

```
var growing = function (array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    function missing(array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (array[i + 1] !== array[i] + 1) {
                return array[i] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I got two tasks assigned and I need your help. Firstly in the 'growing' function I have to check if array is growing. For example, for array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` it should return true but for `[1,2,10,4,5,6,7]` false. I am completely out of ideas for this loop, how can I upgrade my loop? Secondly, in the 'missing' function, I have to iterate through whole array and check if it's iterating, I mean if array is like this: `[1, 2, 3, 5,]` it shall return `4`, if array is iterating fine without "jumps" it shall return null. When I am trying to add 'else' loop with condition return null; it's just breaking my whole loop and it's returning null for every array. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yow was almost there, see comments in code:

```
var growing = function (array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            return false; // return only when it is not growing
        }
    }
    // if not returned in loop, then array is ascending
    return true;
};

// define function outside of growing function
function missing(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i + 1] !== array[i] + 1) {
            return array[i] + 1;
        }
    }
}

console.log(growing([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])); // true
console.log(growing([1,2,10,4,5,6,7])); // false
console.log(missing([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])); // undefined
console.log(missing([1, 2, 3, 5,])); // 4
```

Comment: Yep, it works. Thank you for answer and explanation. I understand now, hopefully i will get better with loops in future. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, I suggest to use [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
function isGrowing(array) {
    return array.every(function (a, i, aa) {
        return !i || aa[i - 1] + 1 === a;
    });
}

document.write(isGrowing([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]) + '<br>');
document.write(isGrowing([1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7]) + '<br>');
document.write(isGrowing([1, 2, 3, 5, ]) + '<br>');
```